# Get the data from a nested array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Can someone help me to filter the array data what is there in "promotion_type": "multi_buy".

I need to filter the data related to the "promotion_type": "multi_buy" section.

```
 const array = [
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "metadata",
                "schema_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "name": "invoice_identifier",
                "value": "DEV16708433389494MO"
            },
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "name": "ordered_at",
                "value": "2022-12-12 11:11:16"
            },
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "name": "billing_invoice_id",
                "value": "bd898352-8824-424a-b3bc-2409250b4e56"
            },
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "name": "unique_sku_count",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "name": "total_item_count",
                "value": "11"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "promotion",
                "promotion_type": "multi_buy",
                "promotion_element_name": "COCA COLA CANS 200 ml Classic - Buy 10 for $8.00"
            },
            {
                "product_sku_id": 85,
                "type": "product",
                "name": "Diet 200ml Each",
                "name_docket": "",
                "variant_info": "1 Unit",
                "quantity": 10,
                "price_inclusive": 95,
                "total_exclusive": 864,
                "total_inclusive": 950,
                "discount_included": false
            },
            {
                "type": "discount",
                "name": "* Promo: COCA COLA CANS 200 ml Classic - Buy 10 for $8.00",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price_inclusive": -150,
                "total_exclusive": -136,
                "total_inclusive": -150
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "surcharges"
            },
            {
                "type": "shipping",
                "name": "Shipping Charge",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price_inclusive": 1500,
                "total_exclusive": 1364,
                "total_inclusive": 1500
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "totals"
            },
            {
                "type": "tax_amount",
                "name": "GST",
                "amount": 72
            },
            {
                "type": "total",
                "name": "Total",
                "total_exclusive": 2228,
                "total_inclusive": 2300
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "other"
            },
            {
                "type": "other",
                "name": "Total savings",
                "amount": 150
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "payments"
            },
            {
                "type": "payment",
                "id": 2044,
                "identifier": "41a9a71a-e719-44e0-b35c-4731599cc413",
                "name": "Credit Card",
                "description": "Visa ending in 1111",
                "amount": 2300,
                "status": "success"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

```
      const soft = array[1]?.filter(({ categories }) =>
        categories?.some(({ promotion_type }) => promotion_type === 'multi_buy')
      );
```

This is the method that I tried but it didn't work. I found this method in a stack overflow. But it was not useful for me because it is specifying a specific array. And in my case, the array is been updated dynamically.

I need to filter only this bit of data.

```
[
            {
                "type": "metadata",
                "group_type": "promotion",
                "promotion_type": "multi_buy",
                "promotion_element_name": "COCA COLA CANS 200 ml Classic - Buy 10 for $8.00"
            },
            {
                "product_sku_id": 85,
                "type": "product",
                "name": "Diet 200ml Each",
                "name_docket": "",
                "variant_info": "1 Unit",
                "quantity": 10,
                "price_inclusive": 95,
                "total_exclusive": 864,
                "total_inclusive": 950,
                "discount_included": false
            },
            {
                "type": "discount",
                "name": "* Promo: COCA COLA CANS 200 ml Classic - Buy 10 for $8.00",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price_inclusive": -150,
                "total_exclusive": -136,
                "total_inclusive": -150
            }
        ],
```

Comment: `array.find(group => group.some(item => item.promotion_type === "multi_buy"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method that worked for me.

```
const promotionalProducts = order?.invoice_items?.filter((item) => {
        return !!item?.find(i => !!i?.promotion_type)
})

const multiBuy = promotionalProducts?.filter((item) => {
        return !!item.find(i => i.promotion_type === 'multi_buy')
})
```

First, filter the data that has the promotions type attribute and then filter the data for the specific promotion type.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a search function like below.

```
function search(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const found = arr[i].some((el) => el.promotion_type === "multi_buy");
    if (found) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}
console.log(search(array));
```